# Where is UIViewController subclass in xcode 4.6

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Sorry if my question looks noob, im new in objective c programming. Im using 4.6 xcode, and when i started to make new built in tab project, then I started to add new UIViewController subclass file, i cant find it. If the template is changed, which template that can provide 3 file (.h, .m, .xib) same with UIViewController. Answer will be appreciate. thanks

Comment: If you can't find the template classes, why not just ⌘+N and make one yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choose the Objective-C class template from the Cocoa Touch section. On the next page, select or type UIViewController in the "Subclass Of" field. Make sure "With XIB for user interface" is checked.

[image]

Comment: thanks, since it change to 4.6 i manually make the .h .m and .xib :)